# Foursquare API: beforeTimestamp ordering is reversed?

Tags: foursquare

I'm requesting a user's checkins at the following endpoint: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins

Items returned are ordered by "createdAt" date descending (more recent checkins first).  When I filter the results by adding a "beforeTimestamp" query string parameter, though, the ordering is reversed.

An example:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?beforeTimestamp=1348711278&limit=1

Expected result: the most recent checkin created before the given timestamp

Actual result: the first checkin ever created

Is this behavior by design?  If so is there any way to specify the ordering/direction?

Thanks.

(I omitted the `oauth_token` and `v` query sting parameters)

Comment: This is indeed strange behavior. We are looking into supporting a ordering parameter. In the meantime, you can use the limit/offset parameters to page through the results.

Comment: @pfhayes Do you have a rough idea when this might make it into production?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @pfhayes Oh nevermind- looks like it's already deployed.  Awesome!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now specify the sorting order of checkins in users/checkins. Use the parameter "sort", with values "newestfirst" or "oldestfirst".